# FileDialog .SelectedItems(1) outlook VSTO add-in is not returning file path

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an Outlook VSTO add-in using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2017, For some reason I needed to pick up file location by clicking a button from ribbon using Excel `FileDialog` via importing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. I've added the code here, The same pattern of code for VBA macro is working fine within outlook's built-in VBA window, but when I execute this code (modified for VSTO Add-In) in Visual Studio Debugging mode it opens the `FileDialog` popup and I can select the single file but `.SelectedItems(1)` is not returning any path in return to output. Your assistance is always highly appreciated. Thanks.

## #

**VBA Code (Worked within Outlook VBA Window)**

```
Sub SelectFile()
  Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3

  Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
  Dim objDialog As Office.FileDialog
  Dim pstPath As String

  Set xlObj = Excel.Application
  Set objDialog = xlObj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select your PST File"
    .ButtonName = "Ok"
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No file selected.")
    Else            
        pstPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox ("You have selected: " & pstPath)
    End If

  End With
  xlObj.Quit()
  Set objDialog = Nothing
End Sub
```

**VBA_Code**

[image: VBA_Code]

And...
**VBA_Output**
[image: VBA_Output]
**..**

## #

**VSTO Code: No File Path in output (Using Visual Studio 2017)**

```
Public Sub SelectFile()

    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Dim objDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim pstPath As String

    xlObj = New Excel.Application
    objDialog = xlObj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With objDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select your PST File"
        .ButtonName = "Ok"
        .Show()

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No file selected.")
        Else                
            pstPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            MsgBox("You have selected: " & .SelectedItems(1))
        End If

    End With
    xlObj.Quit()
    objDialog = Nothing
End Sub
```

**VSTO_Code_VisualStudio17**
[image: VSTO_Code_VisualStudio17]

And... **VSTO_Output**
[image: VSTO_Output]

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to create an instance of the Excel.Application just to use a common file dialog. Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog is the way to go.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I tried but it get an error in debugging mode says `error BC30002: Type 'Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog' is not defined.` I don't know how to define this in vsto outlook add-in project.

Comment: You need to reference the appropriate assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: Method 1 does NOT work with Outlook. Just keeping it included if someone lands here looking for a solution in other VSTO apps.*

### Method 1 (Excel, Word, PowerPoint only)

This is due to zero-based indexing in .NET. Though many VSTO collections use 1-based index, `SelectedItems` is not one of them. Also note that you should never (ever) use `new Application()` in a VSTO add-in. All VSTO add-in by default get `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` (or `this.Application` if you're already in `ThisAddin` class) that you can use to access current application instance.

So your original code should be like this:

```
Public Sub SelectFile()
  Dim objDialog = Me.Application.FileDialog(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select your PST File"
    .ButtonName = "OK"
    If .Show() = -1 Then
      MsgBox("You have selected: " & .SelectedItems(0))
    Else
      MsgBox("No file selected.")
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

### Method 2 (All VSTO and other WinForms/WPF apps)

Since `FileDialog` is not available in Outlook, an alternate way is to use Microsoft.Win32 dialogs for the same purpose. Here is some code from a past project of mine:

```
Public Sub SelectFile()
  Dim openDialog As new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
openDialog.Filter = "Audio files (*.wav, *.mp3, *.m4a)|*.wav;*.mp3;*.m4a"
  If openDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault() Then
   Dim NewAudioFilePath = openDialog.FileName
  End If
End Sub
```

You must add reference to `PresentationFramework` library for this to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick solution. I've changed my existing VSTO `.SelectedItems(1)` to zero based `.SelectedItems(0)` and now Im getting the expected file path. I've also tried the ways you've posted above but both of these stuck with error in visual studio build process. (to be honest I'm very new in VB programming and this is my first outlook add-in). First one got the error `'Application' is not a member of 'TestRib'` as I'm putting all executed code under a button within add-n ribbon. And Second one gets `error BC30002: Type 'Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog' is not defined.` Please advise

Comment: Use Globals.ThisAddin.Application instead of Me.Application if u r in the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks. After adding `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` instead of `Me.Application` it gives another error in debugging mode `System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'FileDialog' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.'`

Comment: Thanks @dotNET, Your effort brings the solutions for me as expected.